# Is it possible to commit a transaction and start a new one without releasing the row locks?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a use case where I need to:

1. Update a row.
2. Persist the changes to disk, such that a system crash will not reverse it.
3. Update the same row that has not been modified by another transaction (a race condition).

How would I achieve this? Is it possible to commit a transaction and start a new one without releasing the row locks?

Comment: Postgres has Advisory Locks with Session lifetime: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS, mybe this helps

Comment: @Turo PostgreSQL surprises me sometimes with features I didn't know it had.

Comment: @Turo Seems like that works. Would you like to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres supports Advisory Locks, that can be hold over Session Lifetime.
If all your threads use these locks, you would be safe.